# When escaping characters in a string, is it faster to test for the need to do so first?

Tags: c#, performance, string-comparison

In cases where there aren't any characters to be escaped, would

```
if (s.Contains("\"")) 
    s = s.Replace("\"", "\"\"");
```

really run any faster than

```
s = s.Replace("\"", "\"\"");
```

The Contains method has to search through the string just like the Replace method does, and if the Replace method doesn't find anything to escape then I'd think it shouldn't really take any longer than the Contains method takes to look through the string.  But if there is a character to escape then you're having to search through the string twice.

Comment: You could always test it and let us know. :)

Comment: if that's your only performance problem, you're a happy man ;=)

Comment: Why do this?  Are you creating some sort of code generator?  Strings in variables don't really need to be escaped.  Only string literals need escaping.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway The first two examples that come to mind are us a string that should be treated as a literal as a part of a Regex pattern, and writing a string that should be treated as a literal to an XML attribute.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Exporting data to Csv.  I just saw someone write it the first way and felt like taking a 5 minute break from work to micro-analyze it :)

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I am a happy man, but I guarantee it's not because this is my only performance problem!  All our data has to be pulled from a remote site via ODBC drivers... and some tables are as large as several 100 million records.  This is just me taking a break from that mess for a couple minutes!

Comment: Was just kidding, take it as an "end-of-day" useless remark (but I've met some questions where the example case you give was the real "use case performance" question)...

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus No worries, I knew you were joking :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some basic performance testing, doing each 10 000 000 times (with a string about 30 characters with a quotation mark somewhere in the middle), gives:

```
Contains("\"")          1327 ms.
Contains('"')           2949 ms.
Replace("\"", "\"\"")   2528 m.s
```

The `Contains` call takes about half the time of the `Replace` call. I thought that looking for a character would be faster than looking for a string, but surprisingly it isn't.

So, comparing the cases of checking first and always replacing to get the break even, where x is the time of the `Contains` call and y is how often you need to do the replacement:

```
x + 2xy = 2x
```

gives:

```
y = 0.5
```

This means that the two methods break even at about 50%. If you need to do the replacement more than half the time, there is no gain in checking for the existance first.

Comment: I did a similar test and got similar results.  My conclusion is that it's not worth the extra line of code to micro-optimize until you're doing about 10,000,000+ at a time.  That's just me though, as I typically prefer to keep my code short and concise at the risk of worse performance as long as the performance gain would be insignificant.

Comment: Just to add a little insight, the reason `Replace` takes twice as long in your case is because the quote is halfway through the string. That means that contains will get halfway, see the quote, and return. Replace still has to check the other half. The two functions actually use the same search algorithm, so in terms of searching, neither is faster.

Comment: And some follow up on the last point: @BrandonMoore should also take into account the nature of his strings. If there is some sort of pattern for where the quote might be located if it exists, the answer may change. For example, if the strings always have a quote as the first or second letter if they have them, `Contains` will be (possibly) significantly faster

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt: I get a very similar result if I place the quotation mark at the end of the string. Even if they use the same search algorithm, the `Contains` method doesn't create a new string, which explains the performance difference. Placing the quotation mark at the beginning of the string only makes the `Contains` call about 25% faster.

Comment: Well also keep in mind that `Replace` is only going to create a new string if it finds a match first. So that has to be taken into account, too. Damn, @BrandonMoore, you're gonna make me do math.

Comment: @Guffa juuuuuust in case you're curious, check out my edit with the equation, adjusted for positions within strings, time it takes to create a new string, etc. And note that I'm totally aware that I just wasted half an hour of my life.

Comment: Wrong test case. You need to measure the negative case. Contains(string) is actually slower than Replace according to my measurements. Although there will be extra cost for Replace when string is longer.

Comment: @FengYuan: I kept the test simple, as the performance will vary between processors, architectures and framework implementations anyway. You are right that the `Replace` will be considerably faster when there is nothing to replace, but some more testing shows that `Contains` is still faster, and the difference is bigger in x86 mode than in x64. There is a break even somewhere, so you could still use it to shave off some cycles in some specific situations.

Answer (score 1):

Andre Calil's micro-benchmark modified:

```
        List<string> StringList = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            StringList.Add(DateTime.Now.Ticks + " abc ");
        }

        string temp;

        KeyValuePair<string, string>[] StringsToReplace = new KeyValuePair<string, string>[6];

        // Use array to avoid dictionary access cost
        StringsToReplace[0] = new KeyValuePair<string,string>("1", ".1.");
        StringsToReplace[1] = new KeyValuePair<string,string>("a", "z");
        StringsToReplace[2] = new KeyValuePair<string,string>("b", "x");
        StringsToReplace[3] = new KeyValuePair<string,string>("c", "v");
        StringsToReplace[4] = new KeyValuePair<string,string>("d", "u");
        StringsToReplace[5] = new KeyValuePair<string,string>("e", "t");

        int TotalIterations = 100;
        Stopwatch stopWatch1 = new Stopwatch();
        Stopwatch stopWatch2 = new Stopwatch();

        GC.Collect(); // remove influence of garbage objects

        for (int j = 0; j <= TotalIterations; j++)
        {
            stopWatch1.Start(); // StopWatch Start/Stop does its own accumation

            for (int i = 0; i < StringList.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < StringsToReplace.Length; k++)
                {
                    temp = StringList[i].Replace(StringsToReplace[k].Value, StringsToReplace[k].Key);
                }
            }

            stopWatch1.Stop();

            stopWatch2.Start();

            for (int i = 0; i < StringList.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < StringsToReplace.Length; k++)
                {
                    if (StringList[i].Contains(StringsToReplace[k].Value))
                        temp = StringList[i].Replace(StringsToReplace[k].Value, StringsToReplace[k].Key);
                }
            }

            stopWatch2.Stop();

            if (j == 0) // discard first run, warm only
            {
                stopWatch1.Reset();
                stopWatch2.Reset();
            }
        }

        // Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds return in double, more accurate than ElapsedMilliseconds
        Console.WriteLine("Replace           : {0:N3} ms", stopWatch1.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds / TotalIterations);
        Console.WriteLine("Contains > Replace: {0:N3} ms", stopWatch2.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds / TotalIterations);
```

Results in favor of directly calling Replace because real replacement is needed 50% of time:

```
Replace           : 7.453 ms
Contains > Replace: 8.381 ms
```

Comment: I disagree with `KeyValuePair[]` vc `Dictionary`, but using 2 stopwatches and the double were smart. +1 for that

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the ratio of strings needing fixup to all strings. If very little strings must be fixed this is certainly a win. The win will be very small though as Replace surely doesn't allocate a new string if it doesn't find any match. This is a common optimization.

The break-even point cannot be predicted, though. Measure.

Answer (score 0):

As with all performance-related questions, the answer is *measure*.

It depends on how intelligent `Replace` is (does it allocate any memory "in advance"? if so, how big a performance hit is that?), on the ratio of strings that need replacements over the total number of strings you process, on the lengths of the strings, which index the first `"` is located at (`Contains` is faster if it can return `true` sooner) etc.

Answer (score 0):

[`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1)

> This method performs an ordinal (case-sensitive and
>   culture-insensitive) search to find oldValue.

[`String.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx)

> This method performs an ordinal (case-sensitive and
>   culture-insensitive) comparison. The search begins at the first
>   character position of this string and continues through the last
>   character position.

so, I'd say that there's no pratical difference. Still, I'll run a micro-benchmarking here.

---

**Micro benchmarking** (man, I love this)

The code:

```
        List<string> StringList = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            StringList.Add(DateTime.Now.Ticks + " abc ");
        }

        string temp;

        Dictionary<string, string> StringsToReplace = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        StringsToReplace.Add("1", ".1.");
        StringsToReplace.Add("a", "z");
        StringsToReplace.Add("b", "x");
        StringsToReplace.Add("c", "v");
        StringsToReplace.Add("d", "u");
        StringsToReplace.Add("e", "t");

        long ReplaceElapsedTime = 0;
        long ContainsReplaceElapsedTime = 0;

        int TotalIterations = 10000;

        for (int j = 0; j < TotalIterations; j++)
        {
            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();

            for (int i = 0; i < StringList.Count; i++)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> CurrentPair in StringsToReplace)
                {
                    temp = StringList[i].Replace(CurrentPair.Value, CurrentPair.Key);
                }
            }

            stopWatch.Stop();

            ReplaceElapsedTime += stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            stopWatch.Reset();
            stopWatch.Start();

            for (int i = 0; i < StringList.Count; i++)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> CurrentPair in StringsToReplace)
                {
                    if (StringList[i].Contains(CurrentPair.Value))
                        temp = StringList[i].Replace(CurrentPair.Value, CurrentPair.Key);
                }
            }

            stopWatch.Stop();

            ContainsReplaceElapsedTime += stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Replace: {0} ms", ReplaceElapsedTime/TotalIterations));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Contains > Replace: {0} ms", ContainsReplaceElapsedTime/TotalIterations));

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Results:

```
Replace: 14 ms 
Contains > Replace: 14 ms
```

=)

Comment: Your micro benchmark needs a few improvements: 1) Move measurement out of the loop 2) avoid dictionary enum, 3) Do not use ElapsedMillionseconds which returns int.

Comment: @FengYuan Thanks for your feedback, however: 1) I **want** to measure each interaction, that's why I keep it inside the loop 2) `Dictionary` is not an `enum` and it's the fastest way to get the strings to be replaced and 3) `ElapsedMilliseconds` returns a `long` and it's the proper form of time measuring

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is curious (you aren't, trust me), the equation to find out the necessary percentage of strings which need a replacement for the OP's method to be more efficient is (roughly) this:

[image: Yeah, that's right.]

Where:

```
C = Time it takes to create a new string
R = average Ratio of Delimiter position to string length
n = average string length
p = average position of the delimiter (quote in this case) in the string
t = time it takes to search one character of a string
```

So if your percentage of strings that have a quote in them is greater than this -- by all means, use the first method.

This doesn't account for variables I considered negligible, such as time to return, the actual replacement of the character (though you can really include that in `C`), or any kind of compiler optimization that I don't know about.

On a side note: the fact that I just spent half an hour solving the world's most useless equation is a perfect example of why I switched from Math to CS.

Answer (score 0):

New version:

```
        string test = "A quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.";

        int count = 1000 * 1000;

        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            string result = String.Empty;

            watch.Restart();

            for (int c = 0; c < count; c++)
            {
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0: // warmup
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        if (test.Contains("\""))
                        {
                            result = test.Replace("\"", "\"\"");
                        }
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        result = test.Replace("\"", "\"\"");
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        if (test.IndexOf('\"') >= 0)
                        {
                            result = test.Replace("\"", "\"\"");
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

            watch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("Test {0,16} {1,7:N3} ms {2}", 
                new string[]{"Base","Contains-Replace","Replace","IndexOf-Replace"}[i],
                watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds,
                result);
```

Result:

```
Test             Base   3.026 ms
Test Contains-Replace 284.780 ms
Test          Replace 214.503 ms
Test  IndexOf-Replace  64.447 ms
```

So Contains(string) itself is quite slow. The reason is due to NLS (nature language processing API. But IndexOf(char) is much faster.